# Can not downsample a point cloud in open3D

Tags: python, open3d

I am new to open3D pythong binding.

I am trying to downsample a point clout and I have this code:

```
import open3d as o3d
input_file='mypoints.ply'
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(input_file)
voxel_down_pcd = o3d.geometry.voxel_down_sample(pcd, voxel_size=0.02)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([voxel_down_pcd])
```

but when I run the code I am getting this error:

```
module 'open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry' has no attribute 'voxel_down_sample'
```

I got the sample from Open3D website tutorial

What is the problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `voxel_down_sample()` on the `pcd` object. For ex, in your case, it will be like this:

```py
import open3d as o3d
input_file='mypoints.ply'
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(input_file)
voxel_down_pcd = pcd.voxel_down_sample(pcd, voxel_size=0.02)
```

Comment: What does the ```voxel_size``` parameter stand for? This is not stated in the [docs](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.6.0/python_api/open3d.geometry.voxel_down_sample.html).

Comment: @hahnec If your pointcloud is expressed in meters, voxel_size=0.02 will mean the voxel grid will be made up of voxels measuring 2 x 2 x 2 cm. After filtering the pointcloud density is reducted so that you have only one point per such voxel.